airodump-ng unable to capture packets
I'm trying to capture Wi-Fi (802.11) packets on a 2.4Ghz network with a BeaglePlay board using airodump-ng. I have mostly followed this instruction.
The interface was set to monitor mode and was verified with iwconfig.
debian@BeagleBone:~$ iwconfig wlan0mon
wlan0mon  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.462 GHz  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

I then run sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon, but it doesn't capture any frames.
debian@BeagleBone:~$ sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon


 CH  11 ][ Elapsed: 13 mins ][ 2024-07-22 16:22 

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH   MB   ENC CIPHER  AUTH ESSID


 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes

Does anyone have any advice on this?
EDIT:
The chipset used is the WL1807MODGIMOC I double checked and found this
which leads to the conclusion that it's not supported.
At the beginning I had the wrong assumption that it does support monitor mode as iw list showed it under the supported interfaces.
debian@BeagleBone:~$ iw list 
... Supported interface modes: 
 * managed 
 * AP 
 * AP/VLAN 
 * monitor 

I found a working alternative with the Pi zero w.

What Wi-Fi chipset were you using? Is that chipset known to support monitor mode well? Do you know for sure that there was traffic on channel 11 in range of your device during the time you were capturing? Did you have antennas connected to your WNIC?

The chipset used is the WL1807MODGIMOC I double checked and found https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/wi-fi-group/wifi/f/wi-fi-forum/661614/wl1837mod-do-we-support-monitor-mode which leads to the conclusion that it's not supported.
At the beginning I had the wrong assumption that it does support monitor mode as iw list showed it under the supported interfaces.
debian@BeagleBone:~$ iw list
...
 Supported interface modes:
   * managed
   * AP
   * AP/VLAN
   * monitor


Please add the chipset info to the question itself to make the question better and more complete.

Probably iw list lists the modes supported by the driver, not necessarily available for all chipsets the drivers runs with.
